# How to filter a data frame depending on how many chars in each row

Tags: r

Is it possible to filter a data frame by string size?

```
# V1
1 Aa
2 bbb
3 bbb
4 cccc
5 cccc
6 cccc
```

How do I filter to get only `Aa` or `bbb` depending on the number of characters. Because when I do `data[1,1]`, I get factor and it not possible to do `nchar(data[1,1])`.

Comment: `nchar(as.character(data[,1]))`

Comment: You can filter with `subset(df1, nchar(as.character(V1))<=3)`

Comment: Thankyou, that was easy only if i knew.

Comment: Grammar corrections. Code clarification.